# surveymonkey file download in code

Tags: ms-access, vba, surveymonkey

I have a SurveyMonkey survey where users upload files.  I am using MS-Access VBA to extract the answers to all survey questions but I can't download the file in VBA.  I keep getting an authentication error.

```
Dim oStrm As Object
  Dim objSM As Object
  Set objSM = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP.6.0")

  With objSM
    .Open "GET", sURL, False, "{Username]", "{Password}"
    .send
    If .Status = 200 Then
        Set oStrm = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
        oStrm.Open
        oStrm.Type = 1
        oStrm.Write .responseBody
        oStrm.SaveToFile sFileName, 2 ' 1 = no overwrite, 2 = overwrite
        oStrm.Close
    End If
    DoEvents
  End With
```

`sURl` is the URL returned for the SM question.  The URL works fine in a browser after I login to SM.  Anyone know how to download a SM file with code?

Thanks in advance.

Norbert

Comment: You have to find a way to login when using the code as well. Survey Monkey may have a developer API. If not, you might be able to login, copy the cookie, and then use that cookie in your code. (Or login using web-scraping techniques.)

Comment: Oh, look! They [do have an API](https://developer.surveymonkey.com/).

Comment: When we need to access web services with basic authentication, A username and password have to be sent with the Authorization header. Username and password should also be base64 encoded. More info in [Coing is Love](https://codingislove.com/http-requests-excel-vba/)

Comment: If you're able to download answers using VBA you must be authenticating already with their API. That's what I do. I can see file upload defined at
https://api.surveymonkey.net/v3/docs#formatting-question-types
but not download. Ask your account support at surveymonkey.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions.  I tried the authentication technique but I get the same html returned (login page).  I took another look at the Upload file API but I don't see anything about downloading the file.  The issue seems to be that the URL returned in the APi (api.surveymonkey.com) is from the www.surveymonkey.com which requires different authentication which seems to be unknown.  I suggest SurveyMonkey creates a file download API.

Comment: I use the API from VBA and get the json data successfully.  I GET from the endpoint https://api.surveymonkey.net/v3/surveys/1234567890/details with headers "Content-Type", "application/json" and "Authorization", "bearer " & ACCESS_TOKEN which is obtained earlier. The documentation describes the oAuth journey to get the token. https://api.surveymonkey.net/v3/docs